# Setting current working directory when executing a shell process

Tags: scala, process

I would like to call `sbt update` within my source-code, to update multiple sbt projects. In the shell this is easy:

```
cd /path/to/project && sbt update
```

But if I use `scala.sys.process` within my code, it won't remember the `cd` therefore `sbt` is called in the wrong directory. Code like this:

```
import scala.sys.process._
("cd /path/to/project" #&& "sbt update").!!
```

And I didn't find in the documentation any possibility to set sbt's project path via console. It would be nice if something like this works:

```
"sbt -projectPath /path/to/project update".!!
```

If something like that is possible, this would save me a lot of mess! (Especially that it runs on UNIX and Windows.)

Comment: You can try to use Process(cmd, cwd)!! to explicitly set the working directory.

Comment: The title of this question is incredibly misleading. The question has nothing to do with sbt -- it could have been any other program.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use one of the `ProcessBuilder` factory methods on the `Process` object:

```
sys.process.Process(Seq("sbt","update"), new java.io.File("/path/to/project")).!!
```

For more documentation, see the [scaladoc file for the sys.process package](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.sys.process.package). Unfortunately, it does not mention the 'current working directory' arguments, but they are in the documentation of object `Process`.

Comment: I've used the "java" version with `java.lang.ProcessBuilder` and it's `directory` method, but this is more elegant, more scala-like. Thanks for that!