# Running multiple shell commands with wildcards

Tags: shell, scala

Is there an *easy* way to do the following in Scala (or Java). I want to run command line commands from a Scala process, for example:

```
 cd test && javac *.java
```

as a dynamically generated shell script. The `javac *.java` should
happen in the directory `test`. The usual simple

```
 import scala.sys.process._
 ...
 "cd test && javac *.java".!
```

or

```
 "cd test && javac *.java".!!
```

don't work, because Scala misinterpretes the `&&` and the wildcard `*`. I have no
idea why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For what you want, you should enter the string as a command-line argument to `bash`.  (That is, `Process(Seq("bash","-c","cd test && javac *.java")).!`)  The reason is that there is no virtual shell into which you're entering commands that will change state like `cd`.  You have to create one explicitly.

The `process` tools will allow you to chain calls together, but the side-effects of the calls had better be reflected in the file system or somesuch, not in the shell environment.  The `ProcessBuilder` scaladoc [contains an example](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) at the end of the introductory text.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense. In the mean time I have found related questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11790240/how-to-run-unix-shell-commands-with-wildcards-using-java), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111983/java-runtime-getruntime-exec-wildcards) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576767/setting-current-working-directory-when-executing-a-shell-process) that make similar points. I think the Scala documentation could be better on this matter.

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
import scala.sys.process._    

"cd test".#&&("javac *.java").!
```

Equivalent to

```
"cd test" #&& "javac *.java" !
```

Comment: this comment is no longer true, and doesn't help answer the question.