# IOException When Running Process

Tags: scala

Given:

```
$pwd
/home/kmeredith/src/linux_sandbox
$ls a.txt 
a.txt
$cat a.txt 

$
```

I then tried to run a `scala.sys.process.Process` that would append 'hi' to `a.txt`:

```
import scala.sys.process._
import java.io.File

scala> Process( List("echo 'hi' >> a.txt"), new File(".") )
res3: scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder = [echo 'hi' > a.txt]

scala> res3.!
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo 'hi' > a.txt" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 32 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 35 more
```

Note that it also failed when I gave the full path:

```
scala> Process( List("echo 'hi' > a.txt"), new File("/home/kmeredith/src/linux_sandbox") )
res0: scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder = [echo 'hi' > a.txt]
```

Why am I seeing this error?

```
scala> res0.!
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "echo 'hi' > a.txt" (in directory "/home/kmeredith/src/linux_sandbox"): error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$Simple.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:69)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.run(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:98)
  at scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilderImpl$AbstractBuilder.$bang(ProcessBuilderImpl.scala:112)
  ... 32 elided
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
  at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
  at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
  at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
  ... 35 more
```

Comment: Are you sure relative paths work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11576767/setting-current-working-directory-when-executing-a-shell-process

Comment: No, I'm not sure on relative paths (good question). But, it failed too when I passed the full path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.sys.process.ProcessBuilder) DSL for redirecting the output:

```
Seq("echo", "some text") #>> new File("a.txt")
```

Here `Seq[String]` will be implicitly converted to `ProcessBuilder`. Each element of the `Seq` will be treated as an argument of the command (first element `echo`) and properly escaped, so you don't need any extra quoting (and shouldn't put `>>` there).

The file that you pass as the second argument is the `cwd` (current working directory), so in this particular case it doesn't change anything. See "Handling Input and Output" section of the [`sys.process` docs](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.sys.process.package).

Comment: That returned an exit code of 0, `"hi"` was not appended: `$cat a.txt` shows an empty line still.

Comment: Ok, I see. `>>` is treated as a part of the argument. So use the DSL with `#>>`, it works. I will update the answer.